# Calculate the total across rows and carry it to the next row

Tags: pyspark

I have the following table

```
Dt           Ex_values   Add_values    Cancel_values
2021-01-01     4000         1              10         
2021-01-02      0           0              20
2021-01-03      0           5               1
```

The expected output is

```
Dt            Cnts 
2021-01-01    4000
2021-01-02    3991  (4000+1-10 =3991)  
2021-01-03    3971   (3991-20)
2021-01-04    3975   (3971+5-1)
-----          --  
2021-01-31     5000
```

I need to start with Jan 2021 till current date. I think I need to use the Rows Between 1 Preceding function. I am new to pyspark and not sure how to proceed. Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate running total in Pyspark dataframes and break the loop when a condition occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67925344/calculate-running-total-in-pyspark-dataframes-and-break-the-loop-when-a-conditio)

Comment: where does this line come from `2021-01-31     5000` ? please be coherent in you example, only display related input/output. Do not create new data in between that come from nowhere...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. I compute a `value` column based on the [`lag`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lag) function and then I do a cumulative sum :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window


df.withColumn(
    "value",
    F.coalesce(
        F.lag(F.col("Add_values") - F.col("Cancel_values")).over(Window.orderBy("Dt")),
        F.col("Ex_values"),
    ),
).select("Dt", F.sum("value").over(Window.orderBy("Dt")).alias("Cnts")).show()
+----------+----+                                                               
|        Dt|Cnts|
+----------+----+
|2021-01-01|4000|
|2021-01-02|3991|
|2021-01-03|3971|
|2021-01-04|3975|
+----------+----+
```